# Libcurl option to search mail by date

Tags: c++, smtp, imap, libcurl, pop3

Is there any options to search the mail inbox by date using libcurl in c++? Or if this is not possible, is there an option to fetch the mail date or at the least the complete mail header. Any protocol among IMAP/POP3/SMTP is fine.

Presently my program can fetch a particular mail by its id:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX/;UID=2");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using the string `"imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX/;UID=1/;SECTION=HEADER%2EFIELDS%20%28DATE%29"`, the date of a mail with a particular uid in the mailbox can be retrieved (using IMAP). The code snippet is :

```
curl_easy_setopt(curlP, CURLOPT_URL,"imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX/;UID=1/;SECTION=HEADER%2EFIELDS%20%28DATE%29");
```